# Ajax data form serialize prevent double submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm struggeling making my form to preven double submision if i press rly fast the button that triggers the click call. I tried to disable the button after succes but it still send it twice. Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button#rezerva").click(function () {
        var chkArray = [];
        $(".table:checked").each(function () {
            chkArray.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });
        var selected;
        selected = chkArray.join(",");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://rezerv.city/engine/app/add_rezervare.php?mese=" + selected,
            data: $("form#formular_rezervare").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                switch (data) {
                    case "nume_error":
                        $(".msg").html("<p>Vă rugăm completați numele</p>").fadeIn("slow");
                        break;
                    case "tel_error":
                        $(".msg").html("<p>Vă rugăm completați telefonul</p>").fadeIn("slow");
                        break;
                    case "email_error":
                        $(".msg").html("<p>Vă rugăm completați un email valid</p>").fadeIn("slow");
                        break;
                    case "tel_numar":
                        $(".msg").html("<p>Numarul de telefon trebuie sa contina 10 cifre</p>").fadeIn("slow");
                        break;
                    case "adaugat":
                        $('#rezerva").attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                        var ora = document.getElementById("timepicker1").value;
                        var zi_aleasa = document.getElementById("zi").value;
                        var tip = document.getElementById("tipp").value;
                        var id_local = document.getElementById("id_local").value;
                        $("#filtru_zi").load("http://rezerv.city/select_tip_rezervare.php?zi=" + zi_aleasa + "&tip=" + tip + "&id=" + id_local);
                        $(".succes").html("<p class=\'text-center\'>Ati rezervat masa <b>" + selected + "</b> in data de <b>" + zi_aleasa + "</b> la ora <b>" + ora + "</b></p><p class=\'text-center\'><button class=\'btn btn-default\' type=\'button\' id=\'inchide\'>Închide</button></p>").fadeIn("slow");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("A aparut o eroare. Va rugam incercati mai tarziu.");
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to disable the button right after the click event start? and if the call is unsuccessful than enable the button.

Comment: this is the correct answer, i bet there is a more elegant way to fix this but this works for now thnx :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you must disable immediatly when clicked  on subbmit not in the succes

```
selected = chkArray.join(",");
 $('#rezerva"]').attr('disabled','disabled')//ADD THIS
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://rezerv.city/engine/app/add_rezervare.php?mese="+selected,
            data: $("form#formular_rezervare").serialize(),
            success: function(data){ 
            switch(data) {
                    case "nume_error":
                         $(".msg").html("<p>Vă rugăm completați numele</p>").fadeIn("slow");
 $('#rezerva"]').attr('enable','enable')//ADD THIS
                        break;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, i bet there is a more elegant way to fix this but this works for now thnx :). The only thing i change to your code is `$('#rezerva').attr('enable','enable')` to `$('#rezerva').removeAttr('disabled','disabled')`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the handler from an onclick to onsubmit and using e.preventDefault.

```
$("#formid").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //the rest of your code
});
```

Comment: i changed to on submit and for some reason it's submiting nothing, just refreshing my page

Comment: managed to make on submit working only after i added $("form#formid") instead $("#formid"), but the e.prevenDefault is just preventing to refresh page not my multiple submision

Comment: #formid should be set to the form's id that contains the button

Answer (score 0):

I would bind the event listener to the form's submit event rather than the button's click. I know you didn't ask at it in your question, but binding to the form's submit event will give a much better user experience since your user's will still be able to press enter in the form to submit it.

Now, as to your issue, it looks like the problem is with your use of Ajax. The form still submits even though your ajax request hasn't return yet. What you need to do is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          // continue on with your business logic
    });
});
```

Of course the click event works the same way, so if you need to bind to the submit button's click event you can do the following as well:

```
$(function () {
    $("button#rezerva").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // continue on with business logic
    });
});
```

Comment: i used e.preventDefault but i still can double click and send my form twice. Basicly after there are no errors on the succes response i want my button to not send the form again even if button is pressed